# Where should I use mysqli_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I know I have to prevent db injections by using the `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

but where **best** should I use it?

When declaring variables? e.g.

`$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);`

OR

inside the `SELECT` / `INSERT` mysql queries?

OR

somewhere else?

**Also**, do I have to prevent db injection in md5 password? e.g.

`$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, md5($_POST['password']));`

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: If you need your data somehere else than only in DB queries, don´t escape first in a variable. And Quentin is right, drop MD5.

Comment: @deviantfan yes, I will show username and password in the user control panel after login.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to prevent sql injection, you shouldn't even be thinking about escaping. Escaping, while it helps many times, is still not 100% foolproof. There are still ways around escaping when used in combination with a poorly written query.

What you *should* be doing is [preparing](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) your query and [binding parameters](http://php.net/mysqli_stmt_bind_param). It is easy to do and essentially eliminates sql injection as a problem. Personally, once I got used to it, I found it easier. If you like using mysqli, it supports binding. I personally prefer PDO because I like to name my parameters.

There are much better resources for explaining the pros and cons that me rambling right now over what has been said a thousand times before.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

An example of this is here on [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link));
}

$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```